# How to write a GPS routing application wthi Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'm going to write a GPS routing application using Google APIs. So far I know that I have to use Google Directions service to obtain and show the path between two points on a map. 
But How can I show a, for example, rectangle that represents the moving object that is GPS enabled.and How can I move it? should I get lat,lng from GPS and resetting the position of the object?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many example applications for Google Maps API. I think it will be very good start https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Comment: Of course, version 3 is better, I just give you my stored url which is already outdated... i modify my answer..